# TypeORM save freezes / blocks all other threads

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Im using typeorm with a nativescript application. While I upsert data to the local db, i want to have a timer running. So i start the timer before i call entitymanager.save. The timer runs for 1 - 2 seconds... freezes.. then continues running when the query is finished.

The point of this is so that i can show or hide icons on the main screen while the user is waiting for the upsert to finish.

Is there a way that i can let the timer continue running while typeorm does its thing?

Ive tried to
1. Wrapping the .save method in an observable.
2. Wrapping the timer in a promise

```
public uploadAllCodes() {
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  this.counter = this.counter + 1;
  console.log(this.counter);
    if (this.counter === 25) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);


  try {
    await this.Upsert(Codes, this.codes);
  } catch (e) {
    await alert(e);
  }

}

static async Upsert(EntityType: any, Entity: any) {
        let databaseConnection = await this.GetDatabaseConnection();

        await databaseConnection.manager.transaction(async manager => {
            await manager.save(EntityType, Entity, {
                listeners: false,
                chunk: 1000
            });
        });

    }
```

I just want to know if there is a way that i can allow the timer to continue to run while the upsert is taking place.